# Which ECMA-262 (ECMAScript/JavaScript) reference should I use?

Tags: javascript, ecma262

The more I read JavaScript Q&A, the more I come across references to the ECMA-262 <del>sleeping medication</del> reference. I've seen some as [HTML](http://es5.github.com/) in addition to the official [pdf](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

I'd like to link to the HTML references, but I'm hesitant because I don't have the time to verify their authenticity, accuracy or consistency.

Is there a particular ECMAScript reference *other* than the PDF that is trusted, or generally endorsed by the Stack Overflow community?

Comment: If you're really concerned about *authenticity, accuracy and consistency*, you've got to use the official source. If you're willing to accept that which is *trusted, or generally  endorsed by the StackOverflow community*, then you're probably not really that worried about *authenticity, accuracy and consistency*.

Comment: I would actually like to see a community wiki page that contained all of the *right* references to the docs for HTML versions, Javascript, CSS, etc.

Comment: Why are you concerned about accuracy?  Are you implementing something to the specification, or just doing javascript programming? If the latter then you will be writing to the lowest browser you want to support anyway.

Comment: I think the biggest issue is simply *making sure to mention* what version of ECMAScript is being talked about -- and that is just ed3 or ed5 for most conversations.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the ECMAScript documentation is only available as a PDF download. The previous version did have an experimental HTML version but that was a converted version from PDF->HTML which contained a few errors. I think they decided to discontinue the HTML versions because of those errors.

In general it's okay to link to the HTML version here on SO, even although it's an outdated spec. Do always check whether something has changed in that section though - don't link to sections that have changed since the last version, to avoid confusion between the previous and latest versions. Of course, it's always best to simply link to the PDF itself.

Comment: http://es5.github.com/ is one of a handful of HTML clones of the PDF spec. These clones are what I'm referring to.

Comment: Definitely not an official one, but it looks okay to me. I just don't know what the other SO members think :-)

Comment: That's the whole point of my question. I *know* they're not official, and I *know* they look ok, what I don't know is whether they *are* ok.

Comment: @zzzzBov the es5 spec on github is safe to reference in general. It can be accepted that it might be wrong occasionally and that can be fixed. I think in the context of SO it's not that much of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a linkable reference, the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is usually a good option. It doesn't contain the exact text of ECMA-262, but that may very well be a good thing (think laymen).

Plus, considering Mozilla is an active browser vendor, I'd say their desire and incentive to "get it right" is probably about as great as it gets.

And they document well. If there are any possible issues with availability of a feature (whether deprecated or a newer addition), you'll generally find a description of compatibility for other (top) browsers along with "shim" code within the description when available. The [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) even seems to be largely made up of MDN's "Compatibility" code.

Answer (score 0):

Ecma International published ECMAScript 5.1 both as an Acrobat (r) PDF file and as Browsable HTML:

- PDF: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/ECMA-262.pdf
- HTML: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/

The second option may be more official than the "annotated, hyperlinked, HTML version" you mentioned.

However, note that

> The PDF version is the definitive specification. Any discrepancies
>   between this HTML version and the PDF version are unintentional.